# Truncate characters in each word on php

Tags: javascript, php, web

I need to have no more than 25 characters in each word. Yes, I could use break-word:break-all, however, I don't like how it all works against long words.
I wrote a JavaScript function that truncates these words by letter and adds a separator. Could you suggest a better option or rewrite this program in php, since I don't know php very well yet

```js
if(document.getElementById('title_parent') && document.getElementById('title')) {
    document.getElementById('title').oninput = function() {
        const parent = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-project-title')[0];
        parent.innerHTML = this.value ? truncate(this.value,20,'...') : "&nbsp;";
    }
}


function truncate(str,maxWordLength,endLetters) {
    if ("string" !== typeof str) {
        return '';
    }
    const words = str.split(/\s+/g);
    const completedWords = [];
    for (let word of words) {
        if (word.length > maxWordLength)
            completedWords.push(word.slice(0,maxWordLength+1) + endLetters);
        else
            completedWords.push(word);
    }
    return completedWords.join(' ').replace(/\</g, "&lt;");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for a PHP rewrite of your JavaScript function. See comments for step-by-step explanation.

Outputs: `here are some short words and a &lt;really long one> now: pneumonoultramicrosco...`

```
<?php

// Set some default values for max word length and end letters arguments.
// If you pass these, your paremeter values will be used.
function truncate(string $input, int $maxWordLength = 20, string $endLetters = '...')
{
    // No manual type checking required if you use declare(strict_types=1),
    // in combination with type hinting in the argument list.
    
    // foreach() replaces for ... of
    // preg_split() replaces String.prototype.split()
    foreach (preg_split('/\s+/', $input) as $word)
    {
        // strlen() replaces .length
        if (strlen($word) > $maxWordLength)
            // substr() replaces String.prototype.slice()
            $completedWords[] = substr($word, 0, $maxWordLength + 1) . $endLetters;
        else
            $completedWords[] = $word;
    }

    // implode() replaces .join()
    // str_replace() replaces .replace()
    return str_replace('<', '&lt;', implode(' ', $completedWords));
}

$input = 'here are some short words and a <really long one> now: pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis';

echo truncate($input);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the best explanation I've ever seen. By the way, I wonder why I was given -1